CXF WSDLToJava Not Generating Void Return Type
Issue
org.apache.cxf.tools.wsdlto.WSDLToJava is generating one of my methods as returning void instead of the correct type
WSDLToJava has generated a method with the response values as parameters with Holder objects but I would prefer a generated response type.
For example:
public void sampleMethiod(java.lang.String parameterId, javax.xml.ws.Holder<java.lang.Boolean> firstOutput, javax.xml.ws.Holder<java.lang.Boolean> secondOutput)
but I need the return type
